# php listing specific file extension only

Tags: php

I want to make my code to list specific file extension only. I have list of php files and I use this code to list all of then in page

so what I need here is to list specific extiontion only. php files only

right now my code lists all files in same folder

```
<?php 
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
    $string = ' ' . $string;
    $ini = strpos($string, $start);
    if ($ini == 0) return '';
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string, $ini, $len);
}

$files1 = scandir(dirname(__FILE__));

?>

<?php 
foreach($files1 as $myfile){

   if($myfile!='.' && $myfile!='..' && $myfile!='index.php'){
      $value = file_get_contents($myfile);
      $fullstring = $value;
      $parsed = get_string_between($fullstring, '$Cont1 = \'', '\'');
      $parsed1 = get_string_between($fullstring, '$Con2 = \'', '\'');

?>
<?php 
  }
}
?>
```

can some one please post an answer with editing this and show me how do I make it to list php files only?

Comment: You know about [pathinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)?

Comment: I'd use a SPL regx iterator wrapped in a filesystem iterator ... lol ... but that's just the way I roll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps. It will only read files which filenames end with php

```
    <?php 
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
    $string = ' ' . $string;
    $ini = strpos($string, $start);
    if ($ini == 0) return '';
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string, $ini, $len);
}

$files1 = scandir(dirname(__FILE__));

?>

<?php 
foreach($files1 as $myfile){
    if (substr($myfile, -3) != "php")
        continue;

if($myfile!='.' && $myfile!='..' && $myfile!='index.php'){
    $value = file_get_contents($myfile);
    $fullstring = $value;
    $parsed = get_string_between($fullstring, '$Cont1 = \'', '\'');
    $parsed1 = get_string_between($fullstring, '$Con2 = \'', '\'');

?>
<?php 
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

[`glob()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) is pretty much made to do  this exactly, and it avoids regex in a loop, substringing on an arbitrary number of chars, etc.

```
foreach (glob("*.php") as $script) {
    echo "$script size " . filesize($script) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Well, you dont regex yourself, but you use some sort of regex-lite as first glob parameter :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ( untested )

```
$Dir = new DirectoryIterator($dir);
$iterator = new RegexIterator($Dir, '/\.php$/i', RegexIterator::MATCH);
foreach($iterator as $fileinfo) {
     if ($fileinfo->isDot()) continue;

     var_dump( $fileinfo );
}
```

Or even better

```
 $Dir = new FilesystemIterator(__DIR__, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS | FilesystemIterator::UNIX_PATHS | FilesystemIterator::KEY_AS_PATHNAME );
 $iterator = new RegexIterator($Dir, '/\.php$/i', RegexIterator::MATCH);
 foreach($iterator as $fileinfo) {
     if ($fileinfo->isDot()) continue;

     var_dump( $fileinfo );
}
```

This second one lets you skip the dots ('.', '..' etc) and changes all the \ Windows to / Linux style ( mainly for use on windows ), auto-magically.